# Change system variables length in SSIS

Tags: ssis, system-variable

I have source excel file and I need to add the file name to every row, When I select the file name from system variables, the system set 0 as the length. How could I change this value?

Comment: Including a screenshot of the problem might help to solve your problem

Comment: file name of what? the system filename more likely refers to the package location. You probably want the connection string to the file you are processing which is typically a user defined variable in a foreach loop or an object property or a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically done in the data flow with a derived column.

Simply add a column of type string and set the expression to the filename of your excel file (typically through a variable).